# Autoscroll page to Anchor under specific conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I have an account page with sidebar (in the photo)

[image]

I want the page to scroll automatically to **#hello** anchor in tablet and phone mode so in CSS @media 787

I can't find the appropriate jQuery or how to do it clearly.

**I would like a modern and simple method**

As I want this jQuery to **run only in page account and in @media 787px**
it may be useful to specify this rule?

if you use a simple clean method, please share

Comment: Read about **matchMedia**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the width of the viewport is smaller than 788px, and if so, set `location.hash` to the `hello`:

```js
const width = $(window).width();

if(width < 788){
  location.hash = "hello";
}
```

```css
#hello{
  margin-top:2000px;
  display:block;
}

html{
  scroll-behavior:smooth;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="hello" href="#">Hello World!</a>
```